# Android map Activity gets reloaded only once, when I leave ( finish() ) another activity

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I am using Mapbox to show some points in a map. I start a second activity for resultcode, so when I finish I can send some coordinates from the second into the first and calculate a route. 
The problem is that only the first time that I enter the second activity and call finish(), the MainActivity that I return to gets recreated, and this happens only the first time. When I enter and exit again the MainActivity does not reload and everything works fine. This causes me to get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style.addSource(com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.sources.Source)' on a null object reference
```

when generating a navigationMapRoute. I logged mapView and mapboxView and none are null. 
[As you can see](https://youtu.be/yoH7TXO5BMg), if I try to generate a route the first time I enter the second activity it would crash. 
Is it maybe a common thing I still don't know?

Comment: referring to your error message I would suggest you to do an `if-else statement` to "catch" the null case. Your error is caused by a null object. Your data which you are trying to bring into the other activity is null for some reason I believe. For more details I need to see your source code

Comment: I did some debugging and the null reference would be the mapbox style or other mapboxmap element, since the activity is being rebuild and the map isn`t finished loading when i try to create a route it doesn't find it. I just dont understand why only the first time when I return back, the activity recreates. Also I can't find a way to wait for the style to finish loading from outside of onMapReady()

Comment: Can you share more code please?